# Forward Declaring a class in Python with argument restriction?

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, arguments, forward-declaration

I'm using the Spyder  IDE, and I'm trying to figure out a way that I prevent it from showing warnings for forward declarations. I'm new to learning Python, so I don't really understand why the warning shows up. Here's what my code looks like:

```
class Heap: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap_size = 0
        self.internal_list = []
    def add(self, elem: Element) -> int:
        pass #to fill in later

class Element:
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
```

At the line

```
def add(self, elem: Element) -> int:
```

I get the message "Undefined name 'Element'". While there's no errors when I actually execute the program, there are a few things that I want to fix about it. How would I prevent this warning from showing up without having to rearrange the order of the classes? Moreover, how would I make autocomplete work so that the list of attributes of "elem" still show up after I type "elem."?

Comment: So I decided to just abandon the Spyder IDE and stick with using PyCharm. It's better for large scale projects anyways.